# How is walking related to Newton's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

How is walking related to Newton's third law, I know you push on the ground and the ground pushes back, but how does this happen?

Comment: "I know you push on the ground and the ground pushes back" that's exactly what happens. What, specifically, are you asking when you want to know "how" this happens? Newton's third law says exactly that, when you push on the ground, the ground pushes back on you hence you move forward.

Comment: The answer is indeed not trivial. It's more than pushing the ground, you need **friction** to walk. You cannot walk without friction, otherwise you'd just slip backwards and fall on your chest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the microscopic level, the electron charge clouds of the two interfaces repel each other, when they come close together. So essentially, you never touch the ground, you are always separated from it by a distance of the order of atomic radius.

Comment: If you regard electrons as clouds (using QM), then it makes no sense to talk about "contact" at all, in general, unless we loose the definition of "contact" to "enough interaction". That said, I don't see how this answers the question...